# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IQueryable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to delete a user from the database when the button is clicked on the page, but I am getting this error when I create my Delete method in my context.

```
cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApplication4.Models.ApplicationUser>>' to 'WebApplication4.Models.ApplicationUser'
```

Here is my code in my context

```
    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        var delObj = from user in Users select Users.Where(u => u.Id == id);
        Users.Remove(delObj);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Below is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        context.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

My view table has the below loop which adds a button for deleting the user. It sends the userId which I've placed in the model.

```
            @foreach (var user in Model)  
            {  
                <tr>  
                    <td>@user.Username</td>  
                    <td>@user.Email</td>  
                    <td>@user.Role</td>  
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "UserControl", new { id = user.UserId })">Delete user</a></td>
                </tr>  
            }
```

Model:

```
public class UserControlModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

and of course UserID is set in my GET. With everything setup to delete, how can I update my context method to actually remove the user from the database when the ID is sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the delete context, you have to get an element with the current Id. In order to achieve it, you should use FirstOrDefault (the Where clause is not completed until you use FirstOrDefault or ToList).

Try this one:

```
var delObj = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```

Comment: More accurately, the result of the linq expression which is assigned to delObj, is an IQueryable, whereas the orignal poster wants an ApplicationUser. FirstOrDefault is an extension method on IQueryable that will return the first of these.  "Users.First(u => u.Id == id)" returns what is needed. I prefer First over FirstOrDefault here because we probably want to throw when the id is not found.

Comment: @ChiralMichael I am not sure if I understand correctly. @Fenuska wrote correct command and result is not `IQueryable<User>`. Is simply `User`. Here is not point if is used  `First()` or  `FirstOrDefault()`. 
Mentioned as you said `Extension methods` are not defined on IQueryable<T> interface but on `IEnumerable<T>` interface. On `IQueryable<T>` are also accessible because there is inheritance => `IQueryable<out T>:IEnumerable<out T> `

Comment: @PeterM. No, the answer got edited. It *was* an IQueryable. I still reccomend `var delObj = Users.First(u => u.Id == id);` instead. It's preferable to throw here when the id is not found instead of later when you try to access a null delObj.

Comment: @PeterM. Looks like `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`, etc extension methods are re-defined for [IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @ChiralMichael they are not redefined. They are different. IQueryable<T> need `Expressions<Func<....>>` where IEnumerable<T> just `Func<...>`. 
Reason why IQueryable<T> mandatory need `Expression` is because this expression is visited and rewritten to language of data source type. IEnumerable<T> is used when you do Linq-to-Object and IQueryable<T> when you need to do Linq-to-datasource

Answer (score 1):

You got this error  because you are mixing styles to write query, and because your query is not very valid

You want:

```cs
ApplicationUser user;
```

Syntax style you are trying to use usually returns:

```cs
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users;
```

With your syntax you finally got:

```cs
IQueryable<IQueryable<WebApplication4.Models.ApplicationUser>> forEachUserYouGetUser
```

To achieve what you wanted using style youtried to use:

```
// not materialized yet
// This is also IQueryable<ApplicationUser> because IQueryable<out T> derives from IEnumerable<out T>
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users = from user in Users 
                                     where user.Id == id 
                                     select user;

var user = users.FirstOrDefault();
if (user!=null)
{
   Users.Remove(user);
   SaveChanges();
}
```

Simpler way is to change specific line to (also mentioned in another answer):

```cs
var delObj = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```

or

```
var delObj = Users.Find(id);
```

and there is much more methods what you can use to get result you want.